# How to prevent webpack/sass-loader from converting font URLs to data URIs?

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-sass, sass-loader

Given the following webpack v1 loader configuration ...

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader'),
},
```

... and simply importing bootstrap sass in my main .scss file ...

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

... for some reason, this bit from bootstrap sass ...

```
url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff2'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff2')) format('woff2')
```

... gets converted to to this ...

```
url(data:application/font-woff2;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJmNGY4ZTA2NDg0ZjY2ODQzYWY0MzdhYTc0N2Q5NWYwNy53b2ZmMiI7) format("woff2")
```

... which decodes to:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "f4f8e06484f66843af437aa747d95f07.woff2";
```

When what I expect/need is:

```
url("f4f8e06484f66843af437aa747d95f07.woff2") format("woff2")
```

Comment: Are you using `url-loader` in the rule for `.woff`?

Comment: That was the reason, thanks!